# Webpart Button to change values in a filtered list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

Is there a way to create a button that would change the values of the items chosen in a list?

**For example,** let's say I filter all items created in May 2016 and there's a YES/NO column and I need to change all the values of that item with the click of a button. Can this be achieved?

Comment: Yes it can be done. You will need to provide more details to tell you how. Outline is add a HTML button to a Content editor webpart. Then write a javascript function that queries the data set using CAML query, modify it the way you want and sent it back to server. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185011(v=office.14).aspx has code examples.

Comment: Other option is to use a workflow called a "New Quick Step". You can find this in the List Menu in the ribbon of the list. Advantage of this is you don't have to write any code. Disadvantage is that this might be a bit slower than doing it with JSOM.